# Button Group and checkboxes C# to open up individual webpages

Tags: c#

I'm looking to create 4 groups with 8 items in a group with check boxes. After these are checked I'd like individual webpages to open up. I'd like to be able to either click group button 1 to open up 8 pages or to individually check an item and have it open the webpage.  My problem is when I click the group 1 button not all pages open up.  Usually only 6 but I have had random number of pages open up. If i click individual the page opens up fine.  Here is a snippet of the code.

```
private void btnGroup1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control c in groupBox1.Controls)
    {
        if (c is CheckBox)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)c;
            if (cb.Checked == false)
            {
                cb.Checked = true;
                btnGroup1.Text = "Uncheck 1";

            }
            else
            {
                cb.Checked = false;
                btnGroup1.Text = "Check 1";
            }
        }
    }
}

private void chkNYALL_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkNYALL.Checked == true)
    {
        chkNYALL.Checked = true;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("www.google.com");
    }
    else
    {
        chkNYALL.Checked = false;
    }
}

private void NYBAT_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkNYBAT.Checked == true)
    {
        chkNYBAT.Checked = true;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("www.google.com");
    }
    else
    {
        chkNYBAT.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the problem (doesn't seem like it), but some of your code doesn't really make sense. In the CheckedChanged methods, why set the checkbox's Checked property if the if statement already showed it to be set to that value? The preferred method of getting a bool value from a bool is not to compare it but to just use the bool value, i.e. `if (chkNYBAT.Checked) { ... }`. In btnGroup1_Click, btnGroup1.Text will only ever show the result of the last checkbox (because it is in a loop), so I'm not sure what the purpose of that is.

Comment: I have a guess as to the problem. Are some of your checkboxes already checked before clicking the group button? Because your code would uncheck those and then wouldn't start the process for those.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick sample that could get you going.
In this snippet, I am dynamically creating 2 `GroupBox`, into which I am dynamically creating multiple `CheckBoxes`, and 1 `Button`. Each `CheckBox` is subscribed to a `CheckedChanged` event handler, and the button is subscribed to a `Click` event.

When checked, a `Checkbox` will trigger the opening of a page.
When clicked, the `Button` will trigger the opening of all checked pages.

You will notice I use the `CheckBox.Tag` property to host the *`value (aka URL)`*

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OpenWebPageOnCheckboxCheck_46934789
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        GroupBox gb1 = new GroupBox();
        GroupBox gb2 = new GroupBox();
        Button btn1 = new Button();
        Button btn2 = new Button();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitGroupBoxes();
            AddCheckboxesToGroup("check1", "www.google.com", gb1);
            AddCheckboxesToGroup("check2", "www.yahoo.com", gb1);
            AddCheckboxesToGroup("check3", "www.bing.com", gb1);
            AddCheckboxesToGroup("check4", "www.duckduckgo.com", gb1);

            AddCheckboxesToGroup("check1", "www.wikipedia.com", gb2);
            AddCheckboxesToGroup("check2", "www.stackoverflow.com", gb2);

            InitButtons();
        }

        private void InitButtons()
        {
            btn1.Text = "Open checked";
            btn1.Click += Btn1_Click;
            btn1.Location = new Point(145, 5);
            gb1.Controls.Add(btn1);

            btn2.Text = "Open checked";
            btn2.Click += Btn2_Click;
            btn2.Location = new Point(145, 5);
            gb2.Controls.Add(btn2);
        }

        private void Btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Control item in gb2.Controls)
            {
                if (item is CheckBox)
                {
                    if (((CheckBox)item).Checked)
                    {
                        LaunchPage(item.Tag.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Control item in gb1.Controls)
            {
                if (item is CheckBox)
                {
                    if (((CheckBox)item).Checked)
                    {
                        LaunchPage(item.Tag.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void AddCheckboxesToGroup(string cbText, string cbValue, GroupBox gb)
        {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            cb.CheckedChanged += Cb_CheckedChanged;
            cb.Text = cbText;
            cb.Tag = cbValue;
            if (gb.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                cb.Location = new Point(gb.Controls[gb.Controls.Count - 1].Location.X, gb.Controls[gb.Controls.Count - 1].Location.Y + gb.Controls[gb.Controls.Count - 1].Height + 2);
            }
            else
            {
                cb.Location = new Point(5, 5);
            }
            gb.Controls.Add(cb);
        }

        private void Cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
            {
                LaunchPage(((CheckBox)sender).Tag.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void LaunchPage(string pageURL)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pageURL);
        }

        private void InitGroupBoxes()
        {
            gb1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            gb1.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            gb2.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
            gb2.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
            this.Controls.Add(gb1);
            this.Controls.Add(gb2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Blaze I appreciate the help.  Have a great day.